# Laravel Form: Whoops, looks like something went wrong

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-6, laravelcollective

i'm trying to update the users email from an edit page, but when i try to include a Form field to email i get the error "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." in this one. All of the others works correctly.

Here is my code:

```
 {!! Form::label('email', 'E-mail', ['class' => 'col-sm-1 control-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            {!! Form::email('email',null,['class' => 'form-control input-jqv', 'id' => 'email', 'autocomplete' =>
            'email' ]) !!}
        </div>
        @error('email')
        <span class="invalid-feedback d-block"> {{ $message }} </span>
        @enderror
```

[image: image of the problem]

Comment: What is the validation code at controller?

Comment: Check your Laravel logs. Do tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log and trigger the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned any additional packages so I assume you used some tutorial that uses such code but Laravel does not have `Form` builder included anymore.

You should install [separate package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html) using

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

to make those methods working